# How to use Cloud Deploy with Cloud Run without completely resetting service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-deploy

When following the quick start to deploy a cloud run service using Google cloud deploy, everything works fine. I can't figure out, however, how to not have the cloud run service have all of its settings removed. I have some secrets and cloud sql connections that need to be added to the container, but all of that stuff gets deleted whenever a new release occurs. Any tips?

Here is the configuration I'm using for the service:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        run.googleapis.com/startup-cpu-boost: 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: backend
      env:
      - name: DB_USER
        value: postgres
      - name: ApiKey
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: test-key
            key: '1'
      - name: DB_PASS
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: postgres-pass
            key: '1'
```

The command I'm using is `gcloud deploy releases create rel-b256 --project {projectName} --region us-east1 --delivery-pipeline backend-pipeline --images backend={backendPath}`

Comment: You are leaving out important details such as skaffold.yaml and cloudbuild.yaml. Please make your post self-contained.

Comment: I think I’ll just continue to investigate personally and if I find a solution I’ll answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was quite the ride of testing, but I figured out that my issue is that in my service yaml, if the yaml is mis-formatted, that the changes do not get correctly applied. In my case, in spec.template.spec, I had:

```
containers:
- image: backend
env:
- name: DB_USER
  value: postgres
```

when I actually needed:

```
containers:
- image: backend
  env: 
  - name: DB_USER
    value: postgres
```

Updating the yaml seemed to fix my issue and the settings were getting correctly applied to the service as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Save them in an .env file or any other IaC template you wish.

Comment: It's not about not keeping them in the file, I have them in secrets manager. It's that the yaml does not get used at all when deploying the cloud run service. I can confirm that my yaml file does exist in the cloud deploy release, it's just not using any of the configuration options when updating the cloud run service.

Comment: @BernardAllotey - Show the command and configuration that you are using.

Comment: A the guy above said. Show some evidence that you've at least tried to solve the problem yourself. Also it's a valid answer to save them the way I mentioned, or what solution were you expecting?

Comment: @JohnHanley I went ahead and added the configuration file, although it's pretty much everything I followed in the quickstart here: https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/deploy-app-run

Comment: @pythonInRelay The problem is not specifically the secrets, I have them saved in Secret Manager. The problem is that none of the options for the cloud run service I specify in the yaml file are applied. It just creates a default service with 512mb of ram and 1 vcpu

Comment: This is due to the command you're using in the first post.